# Filtering Array - Within contract or via front-end JavaScript?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have the following function within my contract.

```
function getAllLandForSale() external view returns(uint256[]){

        // Get the total number of properties created
        uint256 totalNumberOfProperties = baseContract.getLandArrayLength();

        uint[] memory propertiesForSaleArray = new uint[](totalNumberOfProperties);

        for(uint i = 0; i < totalNumberOfProperties; ++i) {

            address currentOwner = baseContract.getLandOwner(i);

            if(currentOwner == address(0)){

                propertiesForSaleArray[i] = i;

            }

        }

        return propertiesForSaleArray;

    }
```

Lets say the `totalNumberOfProperties` variable is 100,000. Obviously the function is looping through each one and checking the `currentOwner` variable.

Would it be faster to do it like this within the contract or filter through the array on the front-end using Javascript. I come from a PHP, MYSQL background so obviously this would be pretty easy using DB queries but I don't want to take that route.

The reason being these results help to populate a paginated listing page and I would like the user to be able to filter through the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely do this off chain by getting the whole array and filtering off-chain.

Even though a `view` function does not modify state, it is still subject to gas usage and hence `out of gas` if it uses too much computation. So if your array gets too big, it will not be possible to execute this function anymore.

I was unable to find the documentation on that

Comment: Cheers, thats what I thought might happen. Can anyone suggest a fast method in JS to filter out an array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter